# Python - counting non alphanumeric characters in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the occurrences of characters in a column in a Pandas DataFrame. For example, I want to know in total how many times the character `A` appears in the column. The problem occurs when there's a non-alphanumeric character.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['AA', 'BA', 'ABA'], columns = ['col1'])
charset = set("".join(list(df['col1'])))
print(charset)
```

This is the set of characters in the column:

```
{'B', 'A'}
```

```
for char in charset:
    print(char, ' ', sum(df['col1'].str.count(char)))
```

This is the number of times each character appears in the column:

```
B   2
A   5
```

Trying the same again, except with a few non-alphanumeric characters:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = ['AA+', 'BA', 'ABA('], columns = ['col1'])
charset = set("".join(list(df2['col1'])))
print(charset)
```

As expected, the set of characters:

```
{'(', 'B', '+', 'A'}
```

However trying to count the characters now fails:

```
for char in charset:
    print(char, ' ', sum(df2['col1'].str.count(char)))
```

```
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

Is there some way to escape the non-alphanumeric characters, or otherwise get the counts I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because input in [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) is regex, is possible use `re.escape`:

> **pat** : str
>
> Valid regular expression.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = ['AA+', 'BA', 'ABA('], columns = ['col1'])
#list is not necessary
charset = set("".join(df2['col1']))
print(charset)
{'(', 'B', 'A', '+'}

import re
for char in charset:
    #used pandas sum
    print(char, ' ', df2['col1'].str.count(re.escape(char)).sum())

(   1
B   2
A   5
+   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly extending what you have already done, you can use a conditional dictionary comprehension to check that each character in `charset` is an ASCII letter..

```
from string import ascii_letters

>>> {char: df['col1'].str.count(char).sum() for char in charset
    if char in ascii_letters}
    {'B': 2, 'A': 5}
```